# how to make onMouseClicked event work for labels inside an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, mouseevent, label

I have an Array of labels and I want to add an onMouseClicked Event. I tried many ways. my last attempt was adding the mouse event inside of the For Loop block where I created the array of labels. But it still doesnt work. Could you guys please give me some help or advice...

This is my class Calculations, where I am trying to make this mouse event work: I surrounded the important part with hashtags and wrote a comment as well.

```
    package application;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Calculations {

    public Label[] test() {

        Label label = new Label();
        Label lbs[] = new Label[20*20];

        //##################################################################
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 400; i++) {
        lbs[i] = new Label();

        lbs[i].setOnMouseClicked(e -> {     // <-- I tried this way,
            label.setText("X");             //     but it doesnt work

            });
      //##################################################################
        }
lbs[10].setText("x");
return lbs; 
    }
}
```

My Main class: the part where the method from the above is called is surrounded in hashtags:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();

            Scene scene = new Scene(grid, (20 * 20), (20 * 20));
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints(20);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(column);
            }

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            RowConstraints row = new RowConstraints(20);
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(row);
        }


        //##################################################################
        Calculations c = new Calculations();
         int count = 0;
         for (int x = 0; x < c.test().length/20; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < c.test().length/20; y++){
                    grid.add(c.test()[count], x, y);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        //##################################################################


                } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually expecting to happen? The event handler just changes the text of `label`, but `label` is never displayed.

Comment: thank you I just figured it out. it made me think what u wrote and now I solved it. I replaced label with the array lbs[] and this inside a loop